# What is the best way to assert redirections in Selenium?

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc

I am writing a selenium test and I need to assert that the page is redirected. How should I verify this? What would be the best way?

I am using `PHPUnit` and the `PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[assertLocationEquals](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.1/en/selenium.html) - Reports an error if the current location is not equal to the given $location.

```
$this->assertLocationEquals($someNewUrl);
```

Comment: cool thanks! I forgot about that page, so thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

I might also add a

```
$this->selenium->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
```

or if you're really paranoid, a

```
sleep(1);
```

In between the page's call to redirect and the check to see that the new URL loaded.  That should help serve as a buffer in the event of a slightly slower web server response.